# Solving two non-linear equations in Octave

Tags: octave, equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following two equations using Octave:

```
eqn1 = (wp/Cwc)^(2*N) - (1/10^(0.1*Ap))-1 == 0;
eqn2 = (ws/Cwc)^(2*N) - (1/10^(0.1*As))-1 == 0;
```

I used the following code:

```
syms Cwc N
eqn1 = (wp/Cwc)^(2*N) - (1/10^(0.1*Ap))-1 == 0;
eqn2 = (ws/Cwc)^(2*N) - (1/10^(0.1*As))-1 == 0;
sol = solve(eqn1 ,eqn2, Cwc, N)
```

`ws`,`wp`,`As`, and `Ap` are given as `1.5708`, `0.31416`, `0.5`, `45` respectively.

But I am getting the following error:

> error: Python exception: NotImplementedError: could not solve
>   
> `126491*(pi*(3*10**N*sqrt(314311)*pi**(-N)/1223)**(1/N)/2)**(2*N) - 126495`
>   
>    occurred at line 7 of the Python code block:
>   
>    `d = sp.solve(eqs, *symbols, dict=True)`

What should I do to solve this?

---

**Edit:**

I modified the equations a little bit.

```
pkg load symbolic
clear all
syms Cwc N
wp = 0.31416
ws = 1.5708
As = 45
Ap = 0.5
eqn2 = N - log10(((1/(10^(0.05*As)))^2)-1)/2*log10(ws/Cwc) == 0;
eqn1 = N - log10(((1/(10^(0.05*Ap)))^2)-1)/2*log10(wp/Cwc) == 0;
sol = solve(eqn1,eqn2,Cwc,N)
```

And now I am getting this error:

> error: Python exception: AttributeError: `MutableDenseMatrix` has no attribute `is_Relational`.
>   
>    occurred at line 3 of the Python code block:
>   
>   `if arg.is_Relational:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the equations, with unknowns in the base **and** exponent of the same term, highly suggests there is no symbolic solution to be found. I gave a simplified system `(2/x)^y = 4, (3/x)^y = 5` to a couple of symbolic solvers, neither of which got anything from it. So, the only way to solve this is numerically (which makes sense because the four known parameters you have are some floating point numbers anyway). Octave's numeric solver for this purpose is [`fsolve`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Solvers.html). Example of usage:

```
function y = f(x)
  Cwc = x(1);
  N = x(2);
  ws = 1.5708;
  wp = 0.31416;
  As = 0.5;
  Ap = 45;
  y = [(wp/Cwc)^(2*N) - (1/10^(0.1*Ap))-1; (ws/Cwc)^(2*N) - (1/10^(0.1*As))-1];
endfunction

fsolve(@f, [1; 1])
```

(Here, [1; 1] is an initial guess.) The output is

```
0.31413
0.19796
```